# Android:how to show the soft keyboard on the LinearLayout

Tags: android, keyboard

Program's main UI  of my App is divided into two sections, Made up of two LinearLayouts.The LinearLayout above aims to show the aircraft.The LinearLayout  below aims to show the soft keyboard.I want to use keys on the soft keyboard to control the movement of aircraft. For example ,if I press the  key  's' on the soft keyboard,the aircraft will move to the left.But I do not konw how to show the soft keyboard on the LinearLayout below.can you do me a favor?

Comment: On what event are you trying to show soft keyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to make your custom buttons, but you can achieve what you want by

- Embedding an EditText in your layout and make it `invisible` or `gone`.
- Programatically hide/show your keyboard using this [utility class](https://gist.github.com/marteinn/11156524).

Answer (score 0):

Use `windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` in your manifest to show keyboard

Comment: Good answer, but how to capture the input?

Comment: by capturing key events using dispatchKeyEvent

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others here suggested (to show the keyboard) you can use this in order for softKeboard to "do nothing" to your layouts:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

or in your Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

I think you should consider setting buttons in your layout, and not using the android keyboard... but this is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your manifest

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

It shows the keyboard at startup of activity and you can get the key event by overriding `dispatchKeyEvent` and getting `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S` like here

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S){

        //Do whatever you want here
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```